# shadowMask returns error in fragment shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use shaderTerrain from [this example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html).

But i only get this error in console:

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() fragment ERROR: 0:571: 'shadowMask' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:571: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'highp 3-component vector of float' to 'float'
```

ShaderTerrain.js file is not modified. Three.js version r73 (last and the same as in example). Shaders in both examples are the same.

My code:

```
var oceanTexture = api.TextureLoader().load(
  'assets/textures/terrain/dirt-512.jpg'
);

oceanTexture.wrapS = oceanTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var sandyTexture = api.TextureLoader().load(
  'assets/textures/terrain/sand-512.jpg'
);

sandyTexture.wrapS = sandyTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var grassTexture = api.TextureLoader().load(
  'assets/textures/terrain/grass-512.jpg'
);

grassTexture.wrapS = grassTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var rockyTexture = api.TextureLoader().load(
  'assets/textures/terrain/rock-512.jpg'
);

rockyTexture.wrapS = rockyTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var snowyTexture = api.TextureLoader().load(
  'assets/textures/terrain/snow-512.jpg'
);

snowyTexture.wrapS = snowyTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

//scope.materialType = size.useDeafultMaterial ?
//  customMaterial : scope.materialType;

var normalShader = THREE.NormalMapShader;

var rx = 256,
  ry = 256;

var pars = {
  minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
  magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
  format: THREE.RGBFormat
};

var heightMap = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(rx, ry, pars);
heightMap.texture = api.TextureLoader()
  .load('../assets/terrain/default_terrain.png');

var normalMap = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(rx, ry, pars);
normalMap.texture = api.TextureLoader()
  .load('../assets/terrain/default_terrain.png');

var specularMap = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(256, 256, pars); //2048
specularMap.texture = api.TextureLoader()
  .load('../assets/terrain/default_terrain.png');

var terrainShader = THREE.ShaderTerrain["terrain"];

/*var uniformsTerrain = Object.assign(
  THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( terrainShader.uniforms ),
  {
    oceanTexture:   { type: "t", value: oceanTexture },
    sandyTexture:   { type: "t", value: sandyTexture },
    grassTexture:   { type: "t", value: grassTexture },
    rockyTexture:   { type: "t", value: rockyTexture },
    snowyTexture:   { type: "t", value: snowyTexture },
    fog: true,
    lights: true
  },
  THREE.UniformsLib['common'],
  THREE.UniformsLib['fog'],
  THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
  THREE.UniformsLib['shadowmap'],
  {
      ambient  : { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
      emissive : { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x000000 ) },
      wrapRGB  : { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 ) }
  });*/
var uniformsTerrain = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(terrainShader.uniforms);

uniformsTerrain["tNormal"].value = normalMap;
uniformsTerrain["uNormalScale"].value = 3.5;

uniformsTerrain["tDisplacement"].value = heightMap;

//uniformsTerrain[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = sandyTexture;
uniformsTerrain["tDiffuse2"].value = grassTexture;
//uniformsTerrain[ "tSpecular" ].value = specularMap;
//uniformsTerrain[ "tDetail" ].value = rockyTexture;

uniformsTerrain["enableDiffuse1"].value = true;
uniformsTerrain["enableDiffuse2"].value = true;
uniformsTerrain["enableSpecular"].value = true;

uniformsTerrain["diffuse"].value.setHex(0xffffff);
uniformsTerrain["specular"].value.setHex(0xffffff);

uniformsTerrain["shininess"].value = 30;

uniformsTerrain["uDisplacementScale"].value = 100;

uniformsTerrain["uRepeatOverlay"].value.set(6, 6);


var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: uniformsTerrain,
  vertexShader: terrainShader.vertexShader,
  fragmentShader: terrainShader.fragmentShader,
  lights: true,
  fog: true
});

var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 256, 256);

geom.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

scope.visible = new THREE.Mesh(
  geom,
  material
);
```

Comment: Fixed. It was because of migration in `three.js` versions